# Sql distinct group of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql i want get distict sets of rows :  identical group for Characteristic and Value only one time :

The column Characteristic can range from one to 10

Table :

| Name | Characteristic | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | eyes | Blu |
| Mary | hair | blonde |
| Mary | Sex | Female |
| Jhon | eyes | Black |
| Jhon | Hair | Black |
| Jhon | Sex | Male |
| Jhon | Nation | Franch |
| Bill | eyes | Blu |
| Bill | Hair | Blond |
| Bill | Sex | Male |
| Will | eyes | Green |
| Will | Hair | Blond |
| Will | Sex | Male |
| Will | Nation | Spain |
| Lilly | eyes | Blu |
| Lilly | Hair | Blonde |
| Lilly | Sex | Female |
| mark | eyes | Black |
| mark | Hair | Black |
| mark | Sex | Male |
| mark | Nation | Franch |
| Anna | eyes | Blu |
| Anna | Hair | Blonde |
| Anna | Sex | Female |
| Antonio | eyes | Black |
| Antonio | Hair | Black |
| Antonio | Sex | Male |
| Antonio | Nation | Franch |

The result that i want to achieve :

| Group | Characteristic | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | eyes | Blu |
| 1 | Hair | Blonde |
| 1 | Sex | Female |
| 2 | eyes | Black |
| 2 | Hair | Black |
| 2 | Sex | Male |
| 2 | Nation | Franch |
| 3 | eyes | Blu |
| 3 | Hair | Blond |
| 3 | Sex | Male |
| 4 | eyes | Green |
| 4 | Hair | Blode |
| 4 | Sex | Male |
| 4 | Nation | Spain |

and finally if it's possible :

| Name | Characteristic | Value | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | eyes | Blu | 1 |
| Mary | Hair | Blonde | 1 |
| Mary | Sex | Female | 1 |
| Jhon | eyes | Black | 2 |
| Jhon | Hair | Black | 2 |
| Jhon | Sex | Male | 2 |
| Jhon | Nation | Franch | 2 |
| Bill | eyes | Blu | 3 |
| Bill | Hair | Blond | 3 |
| Bill | Sex | Male | 3 |
| Will | eyes | Green | 4 |
| Will | Hair | Blond | 4 |
| Will | Sex | Male | 4 |
| Will | Nation | Spain | 4 |
| Lilly | eyes | Blu | 1 |
| Lilly | Hair | Blonde | 1 |
| Lilly | Sex | Female | 1 |
| mark | eyes | Black | 2 |
| mark | Hair | Black | 2 |
| mark | Sex | Male | 2 |
| mark | Nation | Franch | 2 |
| Anna | eyes | Blu | 1 |
| Anna | Hair | Blonde | 1 |
| Anna | Sex | Female | 1 |
| Antonio | eyes | Black | 2 |
| Antonio | Hair | Black | 2 |
| Antonio | Sex | Male | 2 |
| Antonio | Nation | Franch | 2 |

Comment: Sample data is great, but do you think you can reduce it a bit? (I get lost when I have to scroll a lot.)

Comment: different number of rows must generate different group too.... if i have for betty only a row : 
betty - Hair - Blonde 
this is a different group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STRING_AGG` to join all the characteristics together, then use `ROW_NUMBER` and `DENSE_RANK` to count them. Then you re-join that back to the base table.

For your first query, you can do it like this.

```sql
SELECT
  Groups.GroupId,
  t.Characteristic,
  t.Value
FROM YourTable t
JOIN (
    SELECT
      t.Name,
      t.GroupDefinition,
      GroupId = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.GroupDefinition),
      RowId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.GroupDefinition ORDER BY t.Name)
    FROM (
        SELECT
          t.Name,
          GroupDefinition = STRING_AGG(Characteristic + ':' + Value, '|')
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.Characteristic)
        FROM YourTable t
        GROUP BY
          t.Name
    ) t
) Groups ON Groups.Name = t.Name
WHERE Groups.RowId = 1;
```

The second query is as follows.

```sql
SELECT
  Groups.GroupId,
  t.*
FROM YourTable t
JOIN (
    SELECT
      t.Name,
      t.GroupDefinition,
      GroupId = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.GroupDefinition),
      RowId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.GroupDefinition ORDER BY t.Name)
    FROM (
        SELECT
          t.Name,
          GroupDefinition = STRING_AGG(Characteristic + ':' + Value, '|')
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.Characteristic)
        FROM YourTable t
        GROUP BY
          t.Name
    ) t
) Groups ON Groups.Name = t.Name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6647a4a2ce34e0f5e95d77470666278)

Another option would be to aggregate it into a JSON or XML format, then shred it back out without re-joining the base table.